# matrx with orthonormal columns and multiplication with its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ mxn matrix with orthonormal columns.

So, we have $U^TU=I$ s.t. $I_{nxn}$ identity matrix.

I want to see whether $UU^T=I_{mxm}$ holds.

Is my attempt correct?

Attempt:

suppose $UU^T \neq I_{mxm}$

then multiply both sides with $U^T$ :so,  $U^TUU^T \neq U^TI_{mxm}$

since $U^TU=I$ s.t. $I_{nxn}$, we have $I_{nxn}U^T \neq U^TI_{mxm}$

Finally, $U^T \neq U^T$. A contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travis gave you a good answer for the problem at hand. However, you also asked about your own attempt (which is obviously wrong, if we consider what Travis wrote), and I will try to explan why is it wrong.

Let us consider the most trivial $U$ we can get:
$$U = e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

You assume that $U U^T \ne I_{m \times m}$, which is true for our $U$:
$$U U^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} \ne I.$$

However, the next step is problematic, when you premultiply both sides with $U^T$. In our case,
$$U^T U U^T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix} \color{red}{=} U^T.$$

The problem is that $UU^T$ can be (and, in this case is) a singular matrix. When you multiply two different matrices with the same singular one, you **can** get the same matrix.

The reason this happens is that a singular square matrix represents a linear transformation that reduces the dimension of the space. In other words, it lacks injectivity.

Geometrically observed, it works very much like a projection. It is not exactly a projection, but a composition of a projection and a stretch in the appropriately chosen orthonormal bases -- see [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) for details: you can write $\Sigma$ as the product of a diagonal projection matrix consisting only of $0$ and $1$, and a nonsingular diagonal (hence, *stretch*) matrix.

This, of course, means that different vectors **can**, in general, be projected to the same one.

Answer (score 2):

Since the columns are linearly independent (each column is in the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the other vectors), we have that $\text{rank } U = n$ and $n \leq m$. Now, $$\text{rank }(UU^T) \leq \min\{\text{rank }U, \text{rank }U^T\} = n,$$ but $\text{rank } I_{m \times m} = m$, so if $UU^T = I_{m \times m}$, we must have that $n = m$, in which case the matrix is square and $U$ is invertible. In particular, since $U^T U = I_{m \times m}$, we have that $U^{-1} = U^T$, and left inverses are right inverses, so $$I_{m \times m} = U U^{-1} = U U^T.$$

So, the claim holds iff $m = n$, that is, for square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\neq m$ (otherwise read the other answer):

Since orthonormal vectors are linearly independent (why?), it must be that $\;n<m\;$ (why?) , and thus looking at matrices as linear maps

$$U:\Bbb F^n\to \Bbb F^m\;,\;\;U^T:\Bbb F^m\to\Bbb F^n\;,\;\;UU^T:\Bbb F^m\to\Bbb F^m$$

But the map $\;U\;$ can at most mantain the dimension $\;n\;$, so it can't be that $\;U\;$ is onto, and thus it is impossible that $\;UU^T=I_m\;$

Comment: You are wrong. It must be $n \le m$. For the remainder of the answer, check what Travis wrote in his.

Comment: That's true, @VedranŠego. For some reason I though 4\;n\neq m\;$ .